# How to Pass Result of Promise from Node to HTML Template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, pug

On the server side, I would like to request a file and pass its contents (an array of objects) to the Template Engine Jade. However, right now Jade only displays the passed parameter as a string like this: `[object Object], [object Object] ... [object Object]`. I am asynchronously loading the file from localhost  and am able to console.log its contents on the server side, but just can't transfer it to the frontend.

My server side code is like this:

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');
const fs = require('fs');

 router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var selectproj = req.query.name;
    fs.readFile('reports//' + selectproj + '.csv', async (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return
      }
      // console.log(await neatCsv(data)) shows the data
      neatCsv(data).then((parsedData) => res.render('project', {projname: parsedData} )); doesnt show the data

   })
   // console.log(typeof(selectproj));
 });
```

Can anyone help me figure out the issue? I dont have much experience with Promises so I suspect it may be that.

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: I don't have the code now, but basically I was trying to assign to a variable inside script tags like this: `.script var = projname` so I could access the variable in an external javascript file

Answer (score -2):

You can do it, calling the fs.promises.readFile and working with await / async. Take a look at it:

Example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/read-file-node-ejs-d6ybg

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const neatCsv = require("neat-csv");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const folder = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src");
  const file = folder + "/sample.csv";

  try {
    const data = await fs.promises.readFile(file);
    const parsedData = await neatCsv(data);
    res.render("home", { data: parsedData });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 8080");
});
```

home.ejs

```
<body>

    <div style="max-width: 900px; padding: 30px;">
      <h1>Test reading a csv file</h1>

      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
            <th scope="col">Category</th>          
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% data.forEach((item) => { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= item.title %></td>
            <td><%= item.type %></td>
            <td><%= item.value %></td>
            <td><%= item.category %></td>
          </tr>
          <% }) %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>>

</body>
```

csv

```
title,type,value,category
Loan,income,1500,Others
Website Hosting,outcome,50,Others
Ice cream,outcome,3,Food
```

Result
[image]

Comment: There's no need to create `readFilePromise`. See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options

Comment: Thanks @Phil for your advice.... I already did the correction in the code.

Comment: All good. It's nice to be able to use native, promise-based APIs in NodeJS (finally)